# How to do Type Casting in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm working to rewrite a PostgreSQL query into MariaDB. The query is casting to a float like so:

```
(PARTITION BY "Date")::FLOAT AS r_rate,
```

MariaDB is not liking the `::FLOAT` --- what is the right way to rewrite this to work with MariaDB?

Comment: Are you sure you want `FLOAT`?  What will become of r_rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either `CAST(expression AS DECIMAL(m,n))` or if you really need floating just add `0.0` e.g. `SELECT (expression) + 0.0`. Strangely, MySQL doesn't support casting directly to float...

```
SELECT CAST('10.2' AS DECIMAL(10,2)), '10.2' + 0.0
```

Output:

```
10.20   10.2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f836f96c4ae82a13621f28c5a18b1dd2)